# Provide add-in for Excel Application created in VBA Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am creating an excel application in VBA Access and I need to give that excel application the @Risk add-in and am not quite sure on how to do so.

This is what I have so far:

In this function I create my Excel Application

```
Public Sub riskTreeview()
  Dim XLAPP As Excel.Application
  Set XLAPP = New Excel.Application
  XLAPP.Visible = True
  Dim WKB As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WKS As Excel.Worksheet, WKS2 As Excel.Worksheet

  Set WKB = XLAPP.Workbooks.Open(excelFile)
  loadAtRisk XLAPP

  ...
End Sub
```

The next function, I got from [here](http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=185). The only difference is that I pass the first one my Excel application. This is where I get confused. If the @RISK addin is not found in the excel application, it runs the @RISK executable but this does not add it as an AddIn to the excel application, does it? In any case, when the exe is ran, I get this error:

> Could not attach to the already running copy of Microsoft Excel because it is invisible or unresponsive

```
Sub loadAtRisk(XLAPP As Excel.Application)
   ' This is the folder for the version of @RISK that should be loaded.
   ' If you want to load @RISK 6 or 5 instead, change the 7 to 6 or 5.
   Const AtRiskFolder = "Risk7"
   ' If the @RISK add-in is already open, there's no need to open it again.
   Dim wb As Workbook
   On Error Resume Next
   Set wb = Workbooks("Risk.xla")
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

   ' Risk.xla isn't open, so open @RISK by using the Risk.exe launcher.
   ' It will be in a sub-folder under the Palisade main folder.
   Dim sPath As String
   If Palisade_MainDirectory() = "" Then
       MsgBox "No Palisade key found in System Registry - @RISK isn't intalled.", , _
           "loadAtRisk( )"
       Exit Sub
   End If
   sPath = Palisade_MainDirectory() & AtRiskFolder & "\Risk.exe"
   If Dir(sPath) = "" Then
       MsgBox "@RISK not found at " & Chr(13) & sPath, , "loadAtRisk( )"
   Else
       Shell sPath
       ' Control must pass immediately to Excel.
       Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub
```

The Palisade_MainDirectory() function is simply a helper function to get the right path to the executable.

Comment: FWIW - You aren't currently using the `XLAPP` object anywhere in the `loadAtRisk` function.  You should be checking for @Risk being loaded by using `Set wb = XLAPP.Workbooks("Risk.xla")` - i.e. checking whether it is a workbook open in the Excel Application you started.

Comment: Following on from @YowE3k 's comment, in `Sub loadAtRisk` `Dim wb As Workbook` should be `Dim wb as Excel.Workbook` and `Set wb = Workbooks("Risk.xla")` should be `Set wb = XLAPP.Workbooks("Risk.xla")`

Comment: @chrisneilsen From what I have seen (mainly from using `Scripting.Dictionary` or `Dictionary`) leaving off the `Excel.` in the declaration won't matter as long as it is unambiguous based on the references loaded (i.e. as long as MS Access itself has no `Workbook` object in its library then it should be fine).  But the `Set wb = Workbooks...` causes a problem because it uses a default Excel application instance instead of the desired one.  But it is certainly better to fully-qualify everything everywhere, so your suggestion should be followed.

Comment: Okay thanks. So when I run the @RISK executable, is it theoretically supposed to attach this "Risk.xla" workbook to the existing excel application?

Comment: @LucaGuarro I have never heard of the RISK executable before, so it is very hard to guess what it does. It may simply be an installer for the Risk.xla file, in which case you may need to manually open the Risk.xla file after it is installed (or restart Excel).  Or it may be an application like your own which creates an Excel.Application object (in its case by first seeing if an existing one was open and using it if possible, rather than automatically creating a new one) and, once it is referencing the object, opens Risk.xla within it.  What does its documentation say that it does?

Comment: I believe that it is simply an installer for the Risk.xla file. I have the RISK addin as an automatically added addin. But this only works when I open excel manually. When I create an excel application from code, RISK is not there. Then when I try to run the @RISK exe manually, it tell me that RISK is already running.

Comment: So when I disable the automatic addin and then use my code to build an excel application and run the RISK executable, I get my excel application with the RISK addin as I want. I do get this error though: 
"You have one or more open workbooks with associated VBA macros.  Please ensure these macros are enabled before using Palisade DecisionTools add-ins.

Failure to enable these macros can lead to unpredictable behavior."